# Do I have to append the scraped data before I can extract the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-scraping, frontend

I'm scraping data from another website. So far I have been successfull but I am struggling with one issue. When I've fetched the data I have to append it inside a div in order to extract the correct data using getElementByClassName. Is there any other way I can do this? Can I store the data somehow in a local variable and then extract the data in a similar way?

```
$.getJSON('URL' + encodeURIComponent('websiteURL' + retrievedData.postnr) + '&callback=?', function(data) {
  $(".newHtml").append(data.contents);//Here is where I append the data so I can extract it.
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("The class name that I am looking for");
  for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var header = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].textContent;
    $(".add").append(header);
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      var pris = elements[i].getElementsByClassName("Class name inside with certain content inside the other class")[x].textContent;
      var info = elements[i].getElementsByClassName("Class name inside with certain content inside the other class")[x].textContent;
      $(".add").append("<div class='priser'><h3 class='pris'>" + pris + "</h3>" + "<p class='info'>" + info + "</p></div>");
    }

  }
  $(".newHtml").remove();
```

Comment: Why are you scraping a website? Is that legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to append it to document. You can [create jQuery object on the fly](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), then it can be used extract data using various DOM traversal methods.

```
var myObj = $('<div />').html(data.contents);
var tragetElement = myObj.find('.someClass')
```

```js
var myObj = $('<div />').html('<span class="someClass">text</span>');
var tragetElement = myObj.find('.someClass');

console.log(tragetElement.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```